# NgMask - To support 2 decimal places

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Currently trying to integrate NgMask below.

Does anyone knows if it supports decimal pattern up to 2 decimal places?
eg. 22.00 or 1893.75

I like to limit entry up to 2 decimal places.
Any regular expression that support this?

http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/

Comment: hi use ngBehavior directives to have ngMask for your inputs..[ngBehavior](http://maherashori.github.io/ngBehavior/)

Comment: I am already using http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should work

```
^\d+\.\d{2}$
```

This will require at least one digit before the decimal, and 2 digits after.

Comment: Can't get this working with ngMask. Did you try it on the plugin itself? Cheers

Comment: My apologies, I did not test it. I looked for a fiddle and couldn't find one. You mentioned a regex, so I tossed it out there. Looking at the documentation, it does not seem to support a number indeterminate length. But you could make the number arbitrarily large like `9?9?9?9?9?9?9?9?9?9?.99`.

Answer (score 1):

mask="0*.00" would work if you want to allow numbers with any length before decimal and only two digits after decimal. eg: 23.22, 123452.65 using ng-mask.

Comment: As stated in `angular-mask` docs using `0` number pattern will allow you to use only zero number